# Application can trigger on Explorer?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, mozilla, internet-explorer-9

Ok my first question was not clear so i m sorry about that.
For example when you open your internet browser when you left click on a page, you can see orders like "send to excel","print" etc.. 
For example i installed Babylon dictionary program when i surf on internet when i see unknown word i just simply choose that word left click on it and find babylon translate command so it opens a site like google translate to translate that word.
Or Internet Download manager program, when i surf on internet when i saw a download link i can easy choose that link left click mouse and trigger to download with Internet Download manager program.
Or JDowloader, when i surf on internet if there is a link on explorer JDownloader suddenly store that link.etc

So I want to make an application with csharp like Babylon program, it will be dictionary program, if i open a a web page i want to choose a word and left click it and my application icon will be there if you click that this word will go a database and stored there. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an extension for each browser that you want to support.
Of the major browsers, only IE supports C# extensions.